# How to pass data from view to layout in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

I am new in angular framework. I am working with angular 8.

I am using a layout to show few pages. Where header is included in layout and page-content is also included in layout. Now I want to show title, which will be provided by page-content and shown in header. How can I do it?

**Bellow is the Route:**

[image]

**This is my Layout**

[image]

**This is my Header**

[image]

**This is my view**

[image]

Comment: You can use a service. Create a service file for Layout and inject it to the root level or Layout component. Then you can receive the same service instance in the Layout component as well as in page-content component. In the service file, create a data attribute to store "title", with getters and setters . Now you can set the "title" from page-content and get it from Layout component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options to solve this AFAIK:

- since everything is under the app component, you can have that component be a passthrough for the header title (both can get a value from the app component)
- you can have a service that connects the header itself with other components

I think the second solution is better since it follows the flow of normal Angular operations.

Basically, we want to create a service that has one value: **A title string**
and **one subject** so the service can trigger events and have clients subscribe to that event:

### Header Service

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeaderService {
  private _title: string = 'Default Header Name';
  subject = new Subject();

  changeHeaderTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this._title = newTitle;

    this.subject.next(this._title);
  }

  clear() {
    this._title = 'Default Header Name';
    this.subject.next(this._title);
  }
}
```

Next, we want the header itself to update every time the service's `_title` is updated. So we need to provide the service (which should be a singleton on the app level) and subscribe to the subject once the header view was initialized:

### Header Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'kb-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  // styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name: string = 'Default header name';

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.headerService.subject.subscribe((newTitle: string) => {
      this.name = newTitle;
    })
  }
}
```

Then, all you need to do is inject the `HeaderService` on your screens and change the header title accordingly once the screen loads.
Something like this:

### Screen Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.headerService.changeHeaderTitle('pizza');
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scbj7z) to show this in action.

The timeout was added just to simulate the title changing after a while. you can remove it and it should work fine.